# How can I purchase a limited in roblox using python?

Tags: python, python-requests, roblox

Here's the code I have:

```py
import requests as req
import time

xcrsftoken = req.get("https://roblox.com/home").text.split("Roblox.XsrfToken.setToken('")[1].split("');")[0]

print(xcrsftoken)

ids = [21070012]

for id in ids:
    r = req.post(f'https://economy.roblox.com/v1/purchases/products/{id}', data={'expectedCurrency': 1, 'expectedPrice': 0, 'expectedSellerId': 1} ,headers={"X-CSRF-TOKEN": xcrsftoken})
    print(r)
    if 'TooManyRequests' in r.text:
        print('Too many requests, waiting 60 sec')
        ids.append(id)
        time.sleep(60)
```

The issue is that it gives a response of `401`. From what I can tell, that means It's unauthorized, meaning I have a wrong token. What's wrong is that I have *confirmed* that it's getting the correct token.

Anyone know why this is happening? Help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

### Side note:

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686834/python-roblox-issue-with-buying-limited-items) didn't help me. I tried the answer but it didn't work for me, returning `403` forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

With the Roblox API, 401 indicates that your user is not authenticated. You need to get a `.ROBLOSECURITY` cookie. Never share this cookie because it grants full access to your account.

```py
cookies = {'.ROBLOSECURITY': 'YOUR .ROBLOSECURITY'}
```

This would be where you store your cookies. Then in the request you can use the `cookies` parameter as shown [here](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies).